# Bash script - Floating point exception

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm passing some arguments to an sh script. One of which is:-

```
script.sh type '24.45' send
```

However, when this 24.45 is included in command, the bash script says **28390 Floating point exception**.

This is just used in the script as **${2}** - seen below here;-

EDIT IN

```
 $ffmpeg -i ${1} -r ${2}
```

Any ideas on how can I escape this or include a floater?

Comment: What command it is used in in the script?

Comment: It is not the invocation or the retrieval of the value that is the problem. The problem lies in the usage of that value in your code which you *have not* shared here.

Comment: Agreed. The answer depends on what your code is.

Comment: Added in the code, but I'm not sure how much help that is really. It's as i said, just ${2}.

Comment: @waxical: what is $imager? The error probably comes from the program whose name is contained in this variable. Bash itself cannot do any floating point arighmetics.

Comment: @choroba - it's actually $ffmpeg - sorry, I was writing something else whilst editing. The -r accepts floats.

Comment: Run the script with `sh -x script.sh type '24.45' send` and show the output (if it's not too long).

Comment: If the command is `$ffmpeg`, what is the value of the `$ffmpeg` variable?  Or is it just `ffmpeg`?  In either case, it's that command, not `sh` or your script, that's getting the floating point exception.

Comment: The command translates to ffmpeg, I used a variable to link to src location. The command works absolutely fine with straight fps (the -r). I found ffmpeg accepts fraction, so supplied in fraction and same error.

Comment: Side note: Variables should always be quoted, but that's not likely your problem. Do `"$2"` (you can use the curly braces, but they're not necessary for positional parameters 0-9). It's not necessary to quote the argument 24.45. Try invoking ffmpeg with those arguments from the command line. You'll probably get the same error. By the way, where are you using `"$3"`?

Answer (score -1):

Try using 'bc' which handles floating points rather well.